# Search All Views For A Field

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 and I need to find views that are still being used that contain the old naming convention so I can update the field name(s).  These views are all central to one Server & Database, but I am not quite sure of the syntax to do this.  This is what I have currently which will get me a list of all views on the database, but how do I search each of the view names in my list to see if they contain a field named (example only) TaxYear

```
Create Table #T (ID Int Identity Not Null, ViewNames VARCHAR(1000)
Insert Into #T (ViewNames)
Select '['+C.Table_Catalog+'].['+C.Table_Schema+'].['+C.Table_Name+']' TableName
FROM Information_Schema.Columns c
Join information_schema.Tables T on C.Table_Catalog = T.Table_Catalog 
AND C.Table_Schema = T.Table_Schema
AND C.Table_Name = T.Table_Name
Where T.Table_Type = 'View'
Group By '['+C.Table_Catalog+'].['+C.Table_Schema+'].['+C.Table_Name+']'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use something like this:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id)  as OBJ_NAME 
FROM sys.sql_modules 
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, 'IsView') = 1 
AND definition LIKE '%mySearchString%' 
order by OBJ_NAME
```

This will return the name of the view.  I've also used it to search Stored Procedures by changing "IsView" to "IsProcedure"

Comment: As I noted in a comment on the other answer, this method is preferred as it finds the references that are used anywhere in the View, not just those returned in the result set. If a field name is changing, it is important to find those references even if they are just in a WHERE clause or in a CASE statement in the SELECT, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This method takes a little bit of time, I believe I found this on code project and have used it multiple times

```
select table_name, column_name 
from information_schema.columns
where column_name like '%taxyear%'
```

Comment: This does not work in the sense of finding Views that **contain** the field, only those that **return** the field. Meaning, if `[taxyear]` is used in a WHERE condition or even a CASE statement in the SELECT, it would not be found by this query.

Comment: @srutzky - I was unaware of that, thank you for letting me know.

Comment: No problem. You can see the difference by executing this: `CREATE VIEW dbo.FindViewTest AS SELECT name, [type] FROM sys.objects WHERE is_ms_shipped = 0;` and then running your query and the one from the other answer, using the string `'%is_ms_shipped%'` in the LIKE. That string is in the WHERE clause of the View, but is not part of the result set.